# Find the probability of $P(X+Y>1)$ given the X and Y range?

Tags: probability

I have to choose a number betwen **0** and **1** for **X**, $X \in[0,1]$ and then I have to choose a point between **0** and **2** for **Y**, $Y \in[0,2]$. What is the probability of $P(X+Y>1)$?

I understand that I have to find all the numbers for x and y in the given range that are greater than 1.

What I did is the following:

[image]

Basically I found the area but it doesn't give me the correct result:
Surface of rectangle - surface of little triangle= **2- 1/2**= **3/2**

But this doesn't match the given results:
[image]

Comment: Hmm... 3/4 does match (one of) the given results, no?

Comment: Before you go any further, does your value of $3/2=1.5$ make sense in the context of a probability?

Comment: I just wasn't paying attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X+Y>1)=\frac 12 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-x}^{2}dydx=\frac 12 \int_{0}^{1}(1+x)dx=\frac34$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Comment: $1-x<y<2$ and $0<x<1$

Comment: Ok, one more thing if I may ask why did you put 1/2 (constant) out, How did you get this 1/2?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Tnx

Comment: Sorry $Y\sim \text{uniform}[0,2]$ then $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{2-0}$

Comment: I looked at the formula and sa that 1/b-a.. it's ok

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to normalize: $P(X + Y > 1)$ is equal to the surface of the area you draw, *divided* by the surface of the total area (ie, the rectangle of points $0 \leq x \leq 1; 0 \leq y \leq 2$, of area $2$).

You should can notice something is wrong in your answer because your probability is over $1$, which is impossible. :)

Comment: So you are saying that I have to divide by 2 the 3/2?

Comment: Yes. If you compute probabilities by computing surfaces of areas, then the formula is $Probability = \frac{\mbox{area of favorable outcomes}}{\mbox{area of all possible outcomes}}$. Here, the area of all possible outcomes is $2$: the surface of the rectangle.

Comment: O my gosh, I already tought that I've included all possible outcomes...